# flatten/expand objects: am I on the right tracks?

Tags: javascript, forms, object

I want to flatten a multi-level object and vice versa. 
For example:

```
{
    option1:value1,
    option2:value2,
    option3:{
        key1:value31,
        key2:value32
    },
    option4:[value40,value41,value42]
}
```

Would be equivalent to:

```
 {
    option1:value1,
    option2:value2,
    "option3.key1":value31,
    "option3.key2":value32,
    "option4.0":value40,
    "option4.1":value41,
    "option4.2":value42
}
```

This is for small objects, the objective of the flattened expression is to facilitate the data collection in a form and the merge with default options. For example I can have form elements like this:

```
<input name="option4.0" value="value40"/>
```

Is this a standard approach, or is there a better way? Are there libraries that already do this?

Comment: If you're using PHP and you use `<input name="option4[0]" value="value40" />` then on the server side you'll get `$_POST['option4'][0]`

Comment: @Kolink I am working entirely on the client side, no server interaction.

Answer (score 2):

That format ({ option4.2: value42 }) won't work (because the . in the key will be parsed as a dot operator). Instead, you'll need to quote the key:

```
{ 'option4.2': value42 }
```

However, this is very non-standard. Flattening objects is typically not required - if you want to submit such an object to a server, you can use JSON to serialize it without flattening:

```
var stringForServer = JSON.stringify(normalObject);
```

If you're looking for a library to manipulate objects and arrays etc, underscore is probably your best bet:

- http://underscorejs.org/

cheers!

Comment: thx for the reply. One of my concerns is to collect the data from the form and make it a structured object or array. Once I get the object or array, I'm fine.

Comment: I have also corrected the question to quote the keys, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with my idea, it works fine but has a few limitations.

The obvious ones is that a key cannot contain a dot (dots are delimiters with this technique), and keys cannot be numbers (or else the algorithm interprets it as an array index).

Another issue is that it won't work if a value is an empty object or array (e.g. option4:[]).